# Binary(16) as primary key: Lightswitch recognizes GUID but can't write them correctly

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-lightswitch

We **must** use GUIDs, identifying records for an export from SQL Server to MySQL. We've got a table in MySQL like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
  `idImage` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `caption` varchar(1000),
  `preview` blob,
  `lastModified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idImage`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And insert data by this:

```
INSERT INTO `images` 
VALUES (
  -- .NET: Guid.Parse("12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789001")
  UNHEX(REPLACE('78563412-3412-3412-1234-123456789001','-','')),
  'My first sample image',
  NULL,
  '2014-08-26 15:51:25'
);
```

After I setup the datasource in Lightswitch I got this:
[image: Lightswitch recognizes Binary(16) as Guid]
Lightswitch recognizes my GUID primary key!!! Simply Awesome :-)
Here's the screen:
[image: Guid on a screen]
Yeah! That's great!

But now, I'd like to CRUD:

- I cannot create a new record. Lightswitch says: *Data too long for column 'idImage' at row 1*
- I cannot update or delete any exisiting record. Lightswitch says: *Another user has deleted this record.*

**What did go wrong here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is easy to solve. You have to tell the MySQL-Connector to use another (older) illustration of GUIDs.
Normally this is done by adding

```
Old Guids=true;
```

to the connection string.
In your case (Lightswitch project) you have to change this option with the "Data Source Wizard". 
You'll find this in the menu:

**Attach Data Source Wizard > Connection Properties >Advanced Properties**

[image]

That's it!